# How to put an HTML script file in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I've been searching for 6 hours and still haven't found the right answer. I have only little knowledge on coding. So I hope you could help me with this in simple terms...

I have a html file that run a js script. It is a form has something like "if" functions that will show different links depend on the query. I want to put it as a part of my post.

I've tried iframe but the link would show up inside the frame. I've tried target="_blank" but the links are still opening inside the frame.
I want to try include but I don't know where I could put this code. And I'm not sure if this code is the right solution for my problem.

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://calculator-bmi.com/wp-content/themes/genesis-flint/js'); ?>
```

What I only wanted is to put my query form in my homepage. I hope you could help me. Thanks!

Comment: Belongs on: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: use [include](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

```
<?php defined('ABSPATH') || exit;
/*
 * Plugin Name: My lovely custom script for javascript
 * Description: Blah, blah, blah...
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Jixun
 */

function your_namespace_inc_script () {
    wp_enqueue_script ('your_namespace_inc_script', plugins_url('js/my.script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
}

add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_namespace_inc_script');
```

Create a folder under `wp-plugins`, place the php file inside (Any name, I call it index).

Modify the path to the script to your script path (Relative path to the PHP script).